# chrome.runtime.sendMessage not working on the 1st click when running normally. it works while debugging though

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a function in the context.js which loads a panel and sends a message to panel.js at the last. The panel.js function updates the ui on receiving that msg. But it is not working for the first click i.e. it just loads normal ui, not the one that is expected that is updated one after the msg is received. while debugging it works fine.

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
"content_scripts": [{
    "all_frames": false,
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js":["context.js"]
  }],
"permissions": ["activeTab","<all_urls>", "storage","tabs"],
  "web_accessible_resources": 
    "panel.html",
    "panel.js"
  ]
```

**context.js  - code**

```
fillUI (){
    var iframeNode = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframeNode.id = "panel"
    iframeNode.style.height = "100%";
    iframeNode.style.width = "400px";
    iframeNode.style.position = "fixed";
    iframeNode.style.top = "0px";
    iframeNode.style.left = "0px";
    iframeNode.style.zIndex = "9000000000000000000";
    iframeNode.frameBorder = "none"; 
    iframeNode.src = chrome.extension.getURL("panel.html")
    document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
    var dataForUI = "some string data"
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "update UI", results: dataForUI}, 
        (response)=> {
          console.log(response.message)
        })
     }
}
```

**panel.js  - code**

```
var handleRequest = function(request, sender, cb) {
  console.log(request.results)
  if (request.action === 'update Not UI') {
    //do something
  } else if (request.action === 'update UI') {
    document.getElementById("displayContent").value = request.results
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleRequest);
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request,sender,sendResponse) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id,request,function(response){
        console.log(response)`
    });
});
```

**panel.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="panel.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <textarea id="displayContent" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or what can I do instead?

Comment: Move `var handleRequest` block at the top, before you use it. Currently you're adding an undefined variable in addListener. If this is just a copypaste mistake while making this question, note that we can't help as you didn't show how and where exactly these scripts run. Extensions have many different contexts and many ways they can or should interact. See how to make a proper [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm . Yes, it was a copy mistake. I have added more code which might be useful to understand the problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An iframe with a real URL loads asynchronously so its code runs after the embedding code finishes - hence, your message is sent too early and is lost. The URL in your case points to an extension resource so it's a real URL. For reference, a synchronously loading iframe would have a dummy URL e.g. no `src` at all (or an empty string) or it would be something like `about:blank` or `javascript:/*some code here*/`, possibly `srcdoc` as well.

#### Solution 1: send a message in iframe's `onload` event

Possible disadvantage: all extension frames in all tabs will receive it, including the background script and any other open extension pages such the popup, options, if they also have an onMessage listener.

```js
iframeNode.onload = () => {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('foo', res => { console.log(res); });
};
document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
```

---

#### Solution 2: let iframe send a message to its embedder

Possible disadvantage: wrong data may be sent in case you add several such extension frames in one tab and for example the 2nd one loads earlier than the 1st one due to a bug or an optimization in the browser - in this case you may have to use direct DOM messaging (solution 3).

iframe script (panel.js):

```js
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(ownTab => {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(ownTab.id, 'getData', data => {
    console.log('frame got data');
    // process data here
  });
});
```

content script (context.js):

```js
document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function onMessage(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg === 'getData') {
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(onMessage)
      sendResponse({ action: 'update UI', results: 'foo' });
    }
  });
```

---

#### Solution 3: direct messaging via `postMessage`

Use in case of multiple extension frames in one tab.

Disadvantage: no way to tell if the message was forged by the page or by another extension's content script.

The iframe script declares a one-time listener for `message` event:

```js
window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
  if (typeof e.data === 'string' && e.data.startsWith(chrome.runtime.id)) {
    window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data.slice(chrome.runtime.id.length));
    // process data here
  }
});
```

Then, additionally, use one of the following:

- if content script is the initiator

  ```js
  iframeNode.onload = () => {
    iframeNode.contentWindow.postMessage(
      chrome.runtime.id + JSON.stringify({foo: 'data'}), '*');
  };
  document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
  ```
- if iframe is the initiator

  iframe script:

  ```js
  parent.postMessage('getData', '*');
  ```

  content script:

  ```js
  document.body.appendChild(iframeNode);
  window.addEventListener('message', function onMessage(e) {
    if (e.source === iframeNode) {
      window.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
      e.source.postMessage(chrome.runtime.id + JSON.stringify({foo: 'data'}), '*');
    }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

one possible way that worked for me is by using functionality in `setTimeout()` method.

in **context.js**

```
setTimeout(() => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "update UI", results: dataForUI}, 
        (response)=> {
          console.log(response.message)
        }
    )
}, 100);
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way.